# ContentVersion FirstPublishLocationId, specify ShareType `I`

Tags: contentdocument, contentversion, content

If i create a `ContentVersion` e.g. via Apex like so

```
ContentVersion conVer = new ContentVersion();
conVer.ContentLocation = 'S';
conVer.PathOnClient = fileName;
conVer.Title = fileName;
conver.VersionData = Blob.valueOf(data);
conver.FirstPublishLocationId = 'someIdHere';
insert conVer;
```

Or via a rest API like so:

```
POST /services/data/v49.0/sobjects/ContentVersion HTTP/1.1
Host: my-domain.my.salesforce.com
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="boundary_string"
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 523
Authorization: Bearer whatever

--boundary_string
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="entity_document";
Content-Type: application/json

{  
    "Description" : "Marketing brochure for Q1 2011",
    "Title" : "Marketing Brochure Q1",
    "PathOnClient" : "Marketing Brochure Q1.pdf",
    "FirstPublishLocationId":"someIdHere",
    "ShareType":"I"
}

--boundary_string
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="VersionData"; filename="2011Q1MktgBrochure.pdf"

Binary data goes here.

--boundary_string--
```

The `ContentDocumentLink` between my ContentDocument is created with `ShareType` as `V`. I want my `ContentDocumentLink` to be created with `ShareType` `I` (Inferred) such as that if the ownership of the parent record is changed the user can delete these documents without having to explicitly transfer them.

Apart from creating these links manually (which is error prone via API if e.g. upload request succeeds and link request fails), what can we do to set the ShareType to be `I` when `ContentVerison` is inserted

**Update**

I would still love for a way to set this explicitly as we are an ISV integrating with many orgs via a managed package, but the default of `V` can be changed to `I` via a global org preference:
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_files_sharing_set_by_record.htm